# Shower mixer leaking - cannot undo handle

Tags: plumbing, shower, leaking

My shower mixer is leaking. There are no grub screws anywhere to be found. I believe that the pin handle itself undoes and acts as a grub screw. However, I am unable to shift it at all.

Link to actual photo of mixer. Sorry it hard to see the underside due to the dripping water. There is no screw or cover.
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

I am not sure I am attempting the correct thing by undoing the handle and didn't want to force it in case I was wrong. I own this tool and tried using it for grip, no luck.

[image: Text]

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: usually there is small hex screw underneath

Comment: The example you show looks like our might have a cover which would pop off the front of the handle. A pic of your actual unit would be far more helpful...

Comment: thank you, I am trying to upload an image of the unit actual unit. There is no hex screw or cover that I can see.

Comment: @jaytaz OK, you are right, I will delete my answer since I was wrong.

Comment: It looks like indeed your handle is screed in, might be stuck so you need pliers and pice of rubber.

Comment: @jaytaz know what are you doing. Disassemble the valve will not fix it. Eventually you will have to find the model number and shop for parts. Shut down water to th whole hause, replace the part hope it will work.

Comment: @ruskes you are right, I have no idea what I'm doing - just trying to avoid a massive plumber call out fee. I was hoping if I can loosen the handle, then I could turn the water off and figure out what comes next. I thought I would be able to take the part to the plumbing shop and get a replacement. That's my very loose plan but I'm still stuck on the handle. Waiting for my husband to come home to see if he can do anything with it. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: You are courageous and determined.  Good luck, sorry I could not correctly identify your valve. To many on the market that look alike. However there is clear difference between letter M and W, to indetify the manufacturer, so which is it ?

Comment: @ruskes after searching around I believe the W mark is an Australian WaterMark certification mark - so no closer on a brand unfortunately

Comment: I did google photo search and there are many models that look like yours. Do you live in Australia ?

Comment: After looking at those pics my only suggestion is to wrap some tape around the handle (to prevent scratching it) and grip & twist with some big channel-lock or similar pliers. iIdon't see any other way to attack this ...